# How to round elements of large array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have  a large an array with 100000 elemnts ,a sample of the values  looks like :

```
array([[  1.96713769e-01,   5.76482242e-01,   2.26803989e-01,
          7.84528623e-01,   8.38717696e-02,   1.31599608e-01,
          3.49645544e-03,   9.89583476e-01,   6.92006905e-03,
          8.97708472e-08,   9.99999731e-01,   1.79541646e-07,
          1.96615857e-18,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  1.74043502e-01,   6.12687828e-01,   2.13268670e-01,
          8.20000770e-01,   6.81814868e-02,   1.11817743e-01,
          4.36557418e-03,   9.87016637e-01,   8.61778870e-03,
          1.30950035e-07,   9.99999607e-01,   2.61899967e-07,
          3.58177845e-18,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]])
```

How to round the values  into 4f

Comment: `array.round(4)`?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you like this solution:

```
[ round(n,4) for n in arr for arr in a]
```

Or something like this to see the results

```
list([ list(round(n,4)) for n in arr for arr in a])
```

to round you can use any lib you like